# Which normalization rule does this table violate?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have a table `executors` with columns:

```
id(pk) | order_id | executor_id(ek) | execution_price | created_at | selected
1        1                 200               1893883332   NULL
```

So, this table contains all available executors and their price.

When executor is set the field `selected` is changed to `TRUE`.
Also I wonder which normalization rule does this schema violate.

Should I create a separate table where store selected executor? Also how to set constrain on the `selected` to avoid selection some executors?

The `executor_id` refers to external table `users.id`. Version is: 10.4.22-MariaDB

Comment: What's `executor_id` doing?

Comment: For the constraint, [edit] the question and tag your MySQL version.

Comment: Updated, check out please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a check constraint on `selected`, that enforces it to be of only one value *v*. Then put a unique constraint on `(order_id, selected)`. Different rows with the same non `NULL` `order_id` but a `NULL` value in `selected` won't violate uniqueness. But different rows with *v* would. Another value isn't possible due to the check constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE executors
             ( -- other columns
              order_id integer
                       NOT NULL,
              selected boolean,
               -- other constraints
              CHECK (selected = 1),
              UNIQUE (order_id,
                      selected));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=7c6bc0c03c52166151572123142547df)

Comment: Thank you, the `selected` should be unique for each `order_id` not in whole table. I added a remark.

Comment: Maybe create a compose key as `order_id + user_id + selected` and set constrains as unique?

Comment: @AliceMessis: Then just add `order_id` to the unique constraint. See the edit.

Comment: @AliceMessis: Well, as I understand your model, `(order_id, executor_id)` should at least be unique *as well* and `order_id` and `executor_id` should both be `NOT NULL`. So `(order_id, executor_id)` could as well be the primary key. `selected` cannot be in the primary key though, because it must allow `NULL`s.

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: One contemplation, if selected columns rename on `status: INT` `where status = 0` is default, `1 = is selected`, `2 is rejected`. In this case `UNIQUE (order_id,
                      selected));` does not work.

Comment: @AliceMessis: Yes that won't work, but this exceeds the scope of *this* question. Please post another one, if there are fundamental changes in the logic invalidating this question. And maybe make sure this time, that you got everything right from the start and don't need to add other things afterwards and run into the same problem again.

Comment: Okay I will post another, thank you for answer

Comment: Is it possible to set `CHECK (selected = 1 OR 2 O 3)`?

Comment: @AliceMessis: `CHECK (selected IN (1, 2, 3))`. But I believe you'll have more than one dismissed contractor per order. That'll clash with the unique constraint then.